# Docker multiple web sites

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My folder structure is:

docker (folder).

- wordpress (folder).
- wordpress-test (folder).
- drupal (folder).
- joomla (folder).

Is it possiblle start multiple web site at same time?
for example wordpress and wordpress-test?

Answer (score 0):

i use lando + docker, this tool is easy to start diferents sites at same time...
Example wp: https://github.com/civanmoreno/wp-lando
you can reply repo and change "name: wplando" on lando.yml and start project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).